# Unknown sticker on a dark grey 1x2 tile, black lines, printed handled?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars, sticker-identification

I bought a big bundle of LEGO, and I'm trying to find out the sets.

This one is on a dark grey 1x2 tile, with black lines and printed handled.

Can you identify this sticker?

[image: Picture of the piece]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]
[image]

Comes from Set #*[75038](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75038-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)* Jedi Interceptor.

Comment: Many thanks! Unfortunately, I miss too many pieces. I'll move to something else.

Comment: That's cool.  Keep on asking.  That's why we're here;)